# Server side code for Lazy Loading in Android from a Single URL

Tags: android, python, lazy-loading

I have my server side code written in Python and I use a single URL which fetches all the data from the server. I have read a lot of posts regarding lazy loading code in Android. But none of them talks about the server side code. I also read somewhere to use RESTful API. But I am not getting how to use it.

An exemplary code would be of great help.